# Best way to write "if condition" within chef template .erb file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am using a `template` node.erb file within Chef.
I have created an `if` condition within the chef `node.erb` file but it is not working as expected.

```
<% if (node['my_port'] > 0) %>
    - port:8000
<% end -%>
```

Within, my chef attributes, I have listed `node['my_port'] = 8200`

Please suggest what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: You say it isn't working as expected. How is it working? What you have is correct overall, modulo some non-standard syntax and spacing.

Comment: I am getting a blank output and nothing else

Comment: @meallhour bother showing your attribute file ? is it really an integer or a string ? (Ruby should guess but sometimes it is not, specially with code page conversion between windows and *nix boxes)